# Alternative to /proc/interrupts

Tags: networking, interrupts, linux

I would like to obtain information about interrupts assigned to my network cards. Is there any other way, than /proc/interrupts?

Comment: Updated my answer for your question about connecting to the interface name

Comment: There is `/sys/kernel/irq` folder with all information needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two common interfaces to kernel information ( other than syscalls ) and they are implemented as filesystems.  Those two filesystems are /proc and /sys.  sys is a little more organized than proc and newer, but not as user friendly. So it is a little bit better for programmers and to avoid parsing.

If you want the information from the sys filesystem (which lspci parses (see somefile that is outputted by `strace -o somefile lspci`)):

```
$ lspci | grep -i network
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82566DC Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
$ cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/irq
2299
```

Notice the 00:19 relationship between the two commands.  The number returned by the irq file will be the same as first column of /proc/interrupts for the relevant device.

If you want more information on the sys filesystem look at the documentation included with the kernel source, for example the text files in `/usr/src/linux-source-2.6.27/Documentation/filesystems`

**Update:**

> Is there a way to connect the output
>   with interface name?

Sure, if  you play around with sys, you will find there are lots of symbolic links that point to other locations in sys.  For example, in /sys/class/net:

```
[kbrandt@kb: /sys/class/net] ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2009-11-02 11:01 eth0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/eth0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2009-11-02 11:01 lo -> ../../devices/virtual/net/lo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2009-11-02 11:01 pan0 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/pan0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2009-11-02 11:01 vmnet1 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/vmnet1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2009-11-02 11:01 vmnet8 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/vmnet8
```

So to get the irq for eth0, you can just:

```
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/../../irq
```

Comment: Is there a way to connect the output with interface name?

Answer (score 2):

lspci -v will show you which IRQ is assigned to your network card(s).

Cheers